# How to see connected IP addresses on Mac when Internet Sharing over WiFi

Tags: macos, networking

I've turned on Internet Sharing on MacOS via WiFi.

How could I list all the connected IP addresses to the Internet Sharing?

(I need to connect to the RaspberryPi via SSH and I need to find out its IP address)

Comment: Not really development related, but https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/show-active-connections-to-internet-sharing seems to have a few answers.

Comment: A WAP, what you have done by bridging, is a layer-2 bridge, so you only see layer-2 (MAC) addresses because the layer-3 (IP) packets are encapsulated inside the layer-2 frames. A router strips off the frame to reveal and route the packet, but bridges on forward frames based on the layer-2 address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Joachim's comment, I found a proper solution for my usecase.
I'm currently on MacOS Big Sur and the solution was a following command:

```
cat /private/var/db/dhcpd_leases
```

When I connect a raspberry, the raspberry IP address can be found at the top.

Here is an example of the file:

```
{
    name=raspberrypi
    ip_address=192.168.2.8
    hw_address=1,e4:5f:1:68:25:58
    identifier=1,e4:5f:1:68:25:58
    lease=0x618d916c
}
```